# Rails YAML.load_file acting different from development to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I do

```
excel_mapping = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/FdfToExcelMapping.yml")
```

in dev environment the result is a hash of strings

While in production when deployed to heroku `excel_mapping` evaluates to a String.

What am I missing?

```
$heroku run console

config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/FdfToExcelMapping.yml")
=> "LastName:\t\tA FirstName:\t\tB County:\t\t\tC Company:\t\tD MainPhone:\t\tE Code:\t\t\tF Source:\t\t\tG Plan:\t\t\tH Type:\t\t\tI CurrentInsurance:\tJ TypeOfCoverage:\t\tK DateAdded:\t\tM Address1:\t\tO Address2:\t\tP City:\t\t\tQ State:\t\t\tR Zip:\t\t\tS County1:\t\tT Email:\t\t\tU DOB:\t\t\tV SSN:\t\t\tW Eff2Exp:\t\tX Y:\t\t\tY Business:\t\tZ HireDate:\t\tAA Effective:\t\tAB PP:\t\t\tAC CName1:\t\t\tAD CDOB1:\t\t\tAE CSSN1:\t\t\tAF CPP1:\t\t\tAG CName2:\t\t\tAH CDOB2:\t\t\tAI CSSN2:\t\t\tAJ CPP2:\t\t\tAK Spouse:\t\t\tAL SpouseDOB:\t\tAM SpouseSSN:\t\tAN SpousePP:\t\tAO CName3:\t\t\tAP CDOB3:\t\t\tAQ CSSN3:\t\t\tAR CPP3:\t\t\tAS CName4:\t\t\tAT CDOB4:\t\t\tAU CSSN4:\t\t\tAV CPP4:\t\t\tAW"

$rails console

config = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/FdfToExcelMapping.yml")
 => {"LastName"=>"A", "FirstName"=>"B", "County"=>"C", "Company"=>"D", "MainPhone"=>"E", "Code"=>"F", "Source"=>"G", "Plan"=>"H", "Type"=>"I", "CurrentInsurance"=>"J", "TypeOfCoverage"=>"K", "DateAdded"=>"M", "Address1"=>"O", "Address2"=>"P", "City"=>"Q", "State"=>"R", "Zip"=>"S", "County1"=>"T", "Email"=>"U", "DOB"=>"V", "SSN"=>"W", "Eff2Exp"=>"X", "Y"=>"Y", "Business"=>"Z", "HireDate"=>"AA", "Effective"=>"AB", "PP"=>"AC", "CName1"=>"AD", "CDOB1"=>"AE", "CSSN1"=>"AF", "CPP1"=>"AG", "CName2"=>"AH", "CDOB2"=>"AI", "CSSN2"=>"AJ", "CPP2"=>"AK", "Spouse"=>"AL", "SpouseDOB"=>"AM", "SpouseSSN"=>"AN", "SpousePP"=>"AO", "CName3"=>"AP", "CDOB3"=>"AQ", "CSSN3"=>"AR", "CPP3"=>"AS", "CName4"=>"AT", "CDOB4"=>"AU", "CSSN4"=>"AV", "CPP4"=>"AW"}
```

Comment: Should I add code to check on type and parse the string myself? I really would like to know the origin of this annoyance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your YAML file includes tabs "\t" instead of spaces. The YAML spec seems to indicate that spaces are needed for key/value pair separation. http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2775170

Comment: You got it!! thanks for the help. Why do you think it works on my local dev environment?

Comment: I'd guess that psych (the new YAML parser) is being used on one, syck on the other. Psych is the default these days, but won't be there I'd the right prerequisites aren't there when you compile ruby. Check the value of YAML::ENGINE